# Error when calling isFollow() method. Error is "Invalid Pointer"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, javascript, following

I am getting issue while fetching follow information for a site.
I am getting error when calling isFollow() method. Error is "Invalid Pointer".

below is my code

```
    function isAlreadyFollowed() {
clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

socialManager = new SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);
socialActor = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();

var siteContentUrl = window.location;
try
{
socialActor.set_contentUri(siteContentUrl);
//alert('hi');
//getting error at below line
var result = socialManager.isFollowed(socialActor);
}
catch(err)
{
alert(err.message);
}
//alert(result);
```

}

do anyone have any idea regarding this error.

Thanks,

Comment: Not sure it this is the problem, but MSDN only documents using the REST-API for working with following of other actors than users: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945068.aspx

Comment: There is msdn link for using javascript too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn155790.aspx
But still I am unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The only value you've applied to your `socialActor` object is URI. What were you hoping to be returned?

You need to apply a valid *user* to it in order to return `true` or `false` from the `isFollowed` Boolean property. You also need to get it's `value`.

See the example below which expects a valid username as input. An alert will display the current following status of the logged-in user to the `targetUser` and follow/unfollow as required.

An email will also be sent to the `targetUser`. This is a default action.

```
var clientContext;
var followingManager;
var actorInfo;
var isFollowed;
var followedCount;
var user; // "domain\\user" <- note the double backslash

// Get the Following status of the current user.
function getFollowingStatus(targetUser)
{
    user = targetUser;

    // Get the current client context
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

    // Create a SocialFeedManager instance
    followingManager = new SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);

    // Create a SocialActorInfo object to represent the target user
    actorInfo = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();
    actorInfo.set_accountName(user);

    // Find out whether the currently logged-in user is following the target user
    isFollowed = followingManager.isFollowed(actorInfo);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(showFollowingStatus, requestFailed)
}

function showFollowingStatus()
{
    // Is following target user
    if (isFollowed.get_value()===true){
        followingManager.stopFollowing(actorInfo);
        alert("You are no longer following " + user);
    }
    // Is not following target user
    else if (isFollowed.get_value()===false) 
    {
        followingManager.follow(actorInfo);
        alert("You are now following " + user);
    }
}

// Failure callback
function requestFailed(sender, args) {
    args.get_message();
}

// Usage getFollowingStatus('domain\\user')
```